# Using Caesar Cipher to encrypt an existing txt file

Tags: python-3.x, file, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am working on a smal home project where I am required to encrypt a text entered by the user. The text file is created at the first section of the program def personal_save(): but What I want to achieve is that when the user presses the close button at main page the def file_Encryption reads the generated txt file and encrypt it. I have already found a code with a simple encryption and trying to change the code but without luck since I am new in programming world.

I have created a function when the user presses the exit button, then the file should be encrypted with a static encryption key then the root windows should be closed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1030x400')
Label(root, bg="black").place(x=0, y=0)

fname = StringVar(root, value="Your first name")
lastname = StringVar(root, value="Your last name")


def personal_info():
    persinf = Toplevel(root)
    persinf.geometry('800x500')
    persinf.configure(background="light blue")
    ttk.Entry(persinf, textvar=fname).place(x=40, y=110)
    ttk.Entry(persinf, textvar=lastname).place(x=240, y=110)
    Button(persinf, text='Save', width=15, bg='brown', fg='black', command=personal_save).place(x=580, y=450)

def personal_save():
    with open('Personal information.txt', 'a') as f:
        line = f'{fname.get()}, {lastname.get()}\n'
        f.write(line)


def file_ecryption():
    with open('Personal information.txt', 'r') as e:
        encryption_key = 2
        lowerAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        upperAlpha = lowerAlpha.upper()
        numbers = "0123456789"
        decrypted = lowerAlpha + upperAlpha + numbers
        encrypted = lowerAlpha[encryption_key:] + lowerAlpha[:encryption_key] + \
                    upperAlpha[encryption_key:] + upperAlpha[:encryption_key] + \
                    numbers[encryption_key:] + numbers[:encryption_key]
        translation = str.maketrans(decrypted, encrypted)
        cipherText = e.translate(translation)
        print("\nCoded Message:  {}".format(cipherText))
        print("\nFrom:  {}".format(decrypted))
        print("  To:  {}\n".format(encrypted))
        print("Encryption key:", encryption_key)
        root.destroy()


Button(root, text='Add personal information', width=25, bg='brown', fg='black', command=personal_info).\
    place(x=50, y=200)

Button(root, text='Close window', width=25, bg='brown', fg='black', command=file_ecryption).\
    place(x=200, y=200)

root.mainloop()

cipherText = e.translate(translation)
```

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'translate'

Answer (score 1):

When you are opening the file as e then calling e.translate, you are calling translate on the file descriptor, not the contents. First you need to read the contents of e.

Comment: @Marius Bokslag
Ok, thanks! I added this line:
    with open('Personal information.txt', 'r+') as e:
        contents = e.read()
My next challenge is to change the content of the txt file...